# Regex for range 1-50

Tags: javascript

I want to need regex who will create value like:

```
1-50
```

I need the regex should allow values from 1 to 50 with `"-"` sign

Comment: how about such strings `1-09`, `2-22` ? will they be allowed in your case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: No only 2-22

Comment: ok, and what numbers(and how many) are allowed for the first section(before the hyphen) `11-..` ?

Comment: it should be between 1-50

Comment: and why this string `1-09` is not allowed? `9` is between 1 and 50

Comment: okk 0 is also allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex: `/[1-9]{1}-([0-4]{1}[0-9]{1}|50)/gi`
Check with `RegExp.test` method:

```
var pattern = /[1-9]{1}-([0-4]{1}[0-9]{1}|50)/gi;

console.log(pattern.test("1-09"));  // true
console.log(pattern.test("10-90")); // false
console.log(pattern.test("2-49"));  // true
console.log(pattern.test("3-51"));  // false
```